# Do ntfsresize and gparted work on a disk image mounted through the loop device?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, ntfsresize

I need to resize an NTFS partition on a disk for which I have an image (dumped with dd).

I mounted it through the loop device on Linux:

```
# losetup -o 32256 /dev/loop0 disk.img # I got the offset from looking at fdisk's output
# mount /tmp/t /dev/loop0
# ls /tmp/t
[Content of NTFS partition shows correctly]
# umount /tmp/t
# gparted /dev/loop0
```

gparted shows me the disk correctly; it just contains one large NTFS partition I want to shrink.

I have it had it running for one hour now.

Will this work? There is lots of disk access, but the timestamp and size of the underlying file disk.img remain unchanged.

Comment: any idea how well the disk was defragged before you did the `dd` dump?  (alliteration ftw!)  shrinking the partition can involve moving data away from the back of the "disk", which could explain why it's taking so long.  how big is the "disk" and how full is the filesystem?

Comment: On the applying pending operations window, you can click the details drop-down, and then there are more drop-downs for the current action being executed. It shows detailed information of what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, loop devices are indistinguishable from 'normal' block devices for higher layer applications (like gparted). Loop device access [doesn't change](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg438806.html) the timestamp of a mounted file: it is a bug.

Also, while the kernel won't create partition subdevices, you can make them with [kpartx](http://linux.die.net/man/8/kpartx) if you need to (just in case).